# Is there a faster way of extracting row/column submatrices from scipy.sparse.dok_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I am working with `numpy`'s `dok_matrix` sparse matrices and, Matlab-style, need to extract blocks of rows or columns, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
#
# Boolean data matrix X created here
#
print X.shape   #(24000, 110000)
# Size below is approx but shows I need need most of the original rows
rowIndsINeed = np.zeros(22000)  
#
# Populate rowIndsINeed here
#
Xsubmat = X[rowIndsINeed,]  # this is slooooow
```

Questions:

1. Is there a faster way of extracting the submatrix if `rowIndsINeed` contains most of the original indices?
2. What if it's the opposite, i.e. `rowIndsINeed` is relatively short?
3. Does the answer to #1 or 2 change if I extract columns instead of rows?
4. Should I convert `X` to a different sparse format? It does not have any convenient structure, i.e. it's not block or diagonal etc. I also need to do other block operations like "find all rows/columns with number of 1's above N", "find the number of common 0's/1's in rows/columns k1 and k2" etc.

In case it matters, I am running this on a RedHat 6 box with 11GB of RAM

Comment: Are you indexing with a big vector of zeros?  Why?  Have you tried converting to other formats (it's easy) and tried their speed?

Comment: No, the `np.zeros(22000) ` operation is just to preallocate the array since I know how long it will be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a sample random matrix:

```
In [130]: M=sparse.rand(100,100,.1,format='dok')
In [131]: M
Out[131]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [132]: M[0,:]
Out[132]: 
<1x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

An index like yours:

```
In [133]: idx=np.zeros((80,),int)
In [134]: M[idx,]
Out[134]: 
<80x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 480 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

It has returned a matrix with 80 copies of row 0 (80*6=480 nonzero elements).

That doesn't sound very useful.

But let's try some timings:

```
In [142]: timeit M[idx,]
100 loops, best of 3: 13.2 ms per loop
In [143]: timeit M.tocsr()[idx,]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop
In [144]: timeit M.tocsc()[idx,]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.87 ms per loop
In [145]: timeit M.tolil()[idx,]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.39 ms per loop
In [146]: %%timeit m1=M.tocsr()
   .....: m1[idx,]
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 691 µs per loop
```

So converting to `csr` gives a good speed improvement, especially if you can do the conversion once before doing other operations.

You can perform similar tests for other operations.

If your goal is to select the 1st 80 rows of `M` use:

```
In [182]: timeit M[np.arange(80),:]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.1 ms per loop
In [183]: timeit M[np.arange(100)<80,:]
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop
In [184]: timeit M[:80,:]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.63 ms per loop
```